# RMarkdown makefile does not see child document changes

Tags: makefile, r-markdown

I have a project with the following structure:

```
root
    - master.pdf
    - master.Rmd
    /assests/sections/child1.Rmd
                      child2.Rmd
    /assests/bib/mybib.bib
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
PDF_FILE=master.pdf

all : $(PDF_FILE)

clean : 
    rm -f $(PDF_FILE)

%.pdf : %.Rmd
    Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("$<")'
```

If I make changes in `child1.Rmd` or `child2.Rmd` the makefile does not run, as it is only looking for changes in `master.Rmd`. I have tried to incorporate the following into my makefile:

```
INCLUDES := $(wildcard assets/sections/*Rmd)
```

but I am have not had success (it still echos "All files are now up to date"). 
How can I get the makefile to see the child documents?

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
$(wildcard assets/sections/*.Rmd)
```

to the final line of the Makefile...

```
%.pdf : %.Rmd $(wildcard assets/sections/*.Rmd)
Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("$<")'
```

And it now tracks changes inside `assets/sections`.